# React BarChart using D3 scrollable X-Axis

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, bar-chart

I am currently trying my best to implement a bar chart that allows the user to scroll on the x-axis while the Y-Axis remains in place. I am using React as my framework.

```
export default [
  { activity: 'Main Idea and Detail', value: 90, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Character and Plot', value: 80, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Elements of Poetry', value: 70, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Standard 8.10', value: 60, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: '8.1.3', value: 50, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Skill 6', value: 40, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Skill 7', value: 30, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Skill 8', value: 21, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Skill 9', value: 10, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Skill 10', value: 5, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: '8.1.34', value: 50, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Skill 60', value: 40, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Skill 70', value: 30, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Skill 80', value: 21, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Skill 90', value: 10, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Skill 100', value: 5, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Skill 900', value: 100, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Skill 1000', value: 50, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Skill -1', value: 5, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: '8.1.35', value: 50, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Skill 160', value: 40, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Skill 10', value: 30, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Skill 20', value: 21, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Skill 80', value: 10, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Skill 650', value: 5, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Skill 300', value: 100, color: '#2A78E4' },
  { activity: 'Skill 3000', value: 50, color: '#2A78E4' }
];
```

My code I am using to generate my scales are:

```
generateScales = () => {
    const { height, margin, width } = this.state;
    const xScales = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .domain(this.props.data.map(d => d.activity))
      .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
      .padding(0.5);

    const yScales = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([height - margin.bottom, 0]);
    this.setState({
      xScales,
      yScales
    });
  };
```

To generate my scales I use the renderAxis function:

```
renderAxis = () => {
    const xAxisBottom = d3.axisBottom().scale(this.state.xScales);
    const axisLeft = d3.axisLeft().scale(this.state.yScales);
    d3.select(this.refs.xAxis).call(xAxisBottom);
    d3.select(this.refs.yAxis).call(axisLeft);
  };
```

I was trying to use this example as a clue, but I am unable to get this line to properly work "d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", display)" http://bl.ocks.org/cdagli/ce3045197f4b89367c80743c04bbb4b6.

I receive an error that this is not part of the d3 module, but the example is clearly using it. I guess I do not know where to start or how to tackle this problem. I tried to solve it also by using CSS, but to no avail

I was able to create a sandbox and if anybody could give me a clue on how to achieve a scrollable X-axis while having the Y-axis stay in place it will be really appreciated using React. Is the up above example the right place to be looking?

I have tried to solve my issue by using the zoom feature it seems like it's the best solution. I am still running into problems when using d3.event.transform.rescaleX it seems that the rescaleX method does not appear on the d3.event.transform object. I am really frustrated as all the examples appear to be using this function. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

https://codesandbox.io/s/k0pj5m8q93

Comment: I think this is a version mismatch issue. that example you show is using d3 version 3 and you're using version 5. There was a massive refactor between v3 and v4 and I think you're trying to use modules that have been split out

Comment: Thanks. Since I am using version 5 I cannot get access to d3.event.transform.rescaleX and i searched the internet to no avail. I have updated my code sandbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code Sandbox with solution:
https://codesandbox.io/s/4q5zxmy3zw

React Scroll Bar Chart based on:
http://bl.ocks.org/cdagli/ce3045197f4b89367c80743c04bbb4b6

D3 is used for calculation, React for rendering. I hope this will help.